# About the dimension of the kernel of $T$ and $T_{\Bbb C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I want to check if the theorems in red are correct. They seems correct but I need a confirmation. Thank you.

---

**Definitions:**

Let $V$ a real finite-dimensional vector space and it complexification defined by $$V_{\Bbb C}:=V+iV\tag1$$

where is easy to check that $\dim V_{\Bbb C}=\dim V$. Now let $T\in\mathcal L(V)$ and it complexification $T_{\Bbb C}\in\mathcal L(V_{\Bbb C})$ defined by

$$T_{\Bbb C}(u+iv):=Tu+iTv,\quad u,v\in V\tag2$$

---

**Theorems:**

I know that $(S+T)_{\Bbb C}=S_{\Bbb C}+T_{\Bbb C}$ for $S,T\in\mathcal L(V)$, and that $\color{red}{(T^k)_{\Bbb C}=(T_{\Bbb C})^k}$ because

$$(T_{\Bbb C})^k(u+iv)=T^ku+iT^kv=(T^k)_{\Bbb C}(u+iv)\tag3$$

Hence

$$\color{red}{[\ker(T)]_{\Bbb C}=\ker(T)+i\ker(T)=\{u+iv\in V_{\Bbb C}:T_{\Bbb C}(u+iv)=0\}=\ker(T_{\Bbb C})}\tag4$$

Now let $p$ a polynomial. Then, using the above identities, we have that

$$\color{red}{[p(T)]_{\Bbb C}=p(T_{\Bbb C})}\tag5$$

thus

$$\color{red}{[\ker p(T)]_{\Bbb C}=\ker p(T_{\Bbb C})\implies \dim\ker p(T)=\dim\ker p(T_{\Bbb C})}\tag6$$

Comment: I don't see any mistake. To have notation clearer, I would prefer $\dim$ with the used field, sod $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}$.